# Push a transparent page with go_router?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

In order show a drawer that covers my shellroute, i need to push a semi-transparent page on top of my page stack. So far the background remain opaque when i use the

```
GoRouter.of(rootNavigatorKey.currentContext!).pushNamed('myDrawer');
```

I have found a ruse using the traditional Navigator and PageRouteBuilder :

```
 Navigator.of(rootNavigatorKey.currentContext!).push(
                    PageRouteBuilder(
                      fullscreenDialog: true,
                      opaque: false,
                      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => MyDrawer(),
                    ),
                  );
```

Is there a way to use an option like the **opaque** parameter, with go_router, when pushing routes ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [CustomTransitionPage](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/CustomTransitionPage-class.html) for that. You'll have to go to where the `GoRouter` instance of your app is defined and add it like below to list of routes:

```
GoRoute(
       path: '/myDrawer',
       name: 'myDrawer',
       pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage(
           fullscreenDialog: true,
           opaque: false,
           transitionsBuilder: (_, __, ___, child) => child,
           child: const MyDrawer(),
       ),
)
```