# Flutter flow_builder: how to push a transparent background loading page

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutterflow

I am working with flow_builder to manage navigation. What I would like to achieve, is in response to a state change (to a loading state) push an "overlay page" which just shows a Circular progress indicator, obscures a bit the background, and protects the screen from user actions. This page would then be "popped" out when state changes from loading state to a loaded state.

I did manage to push a completely opaque loading page using flowbuilder (fully opaque even when setting a Container with a semi opaque background at the root of the page), but I would like the user being able to see the background.

Conversely, I can push a semi transparent loading page directly using the navigator, using the following code :

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
  PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false, // set to false
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Container(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          color: Colors.white,
        ))),
  ),
);
```

However, using flow_builder, we only maintain a pages stack and think we have limited control on how the underlying Navigator manages Routes from pages. Any insight on how I could achieve my requirement? Should I directly push/pop in the Navigator (which defeats a bit the purpose of using flow_builder in the first place...)? Am I missing another simpler way of achieving this result?

Thanks a lot for your insights!

EDIT: this looks very much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75949913/push-a-transparent-page-with-go-router), but I am using flow_builder rather than go_router for navigation.

Comment: or you can use `Overlay.of(context).insert(entry);`